# What's the difference between these two uses of the && logical operator?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

What is the difference between these various uses of the "&&" logical operator?

From Oliver Steele's Functional.js library.
Line 4, "args.length && arg":

```
0 Function.prototype.partial = function(){
1    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
2    return function(){
3      var arg = 0;
4      for ( var i = 0; i < args.length && arg < arguments.length; i++ )
5        if ( args[i] === undefined )
6          args[i] = arguments[arg++];
7      return fn.apply(this, args);
8    };
9  };
```

From [bootstrap.js](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js).
Line 11 below, "'hover' && this.$element":

```
1 var Carousel = function (element, options) {
2    this.$element    = $(element).on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
3    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
4    this.options     = options
5    this.paused      =
6    this.sliding     =
7    this.interval    =
8    this.$active     =
9    this.$items      = null
10
11   this.options.pause == 'hover' && this.$element
12     .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
13     .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
14 }
```

Also why not just use the + arithmetic operator in the first example?

Here is yet another example that I'm having trouble grokking, from the same Carousel section of bootstrap.js:

```
this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))
```

Comment: && does what they call short circuiting which means that if the left hand operand is false the right hand operand is never checked \ run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's the same operator everywhere, but being used for different purposes by the programmer.

The first code example is not doing `args.length && arg` at all, but is rather doing the equivalent of `(i < args.length) && (arg < arguments.length)` because `&&` has lower precedence than `<`. It means, "loop until either `i` is at or surpasses the argument count or `arg` is at or surpasses the argument count". You can see that `+` is therefore not equivalent in this context.

The other code examples are all exploiting the fact that the logical-and operator (`&&`) "short-circuits" when its left-hand operand is false, i.e. *it only evaluates the expression on the right if the one on the left is true*.

So, `this.options.pause == 'hover' && this.$element.on(...` is a short-hand way of attaching the event listeners only if the pause option is set to 'hover' (because if it's not, the left-hand expression will be false, and the `on` functions won't be called).

Similarly, the final example you found only calls `setInterval` (and assigns the result to `this.interval`) if the desired interval is "true" (I imagine generally non-zero here, but also not undefined, etc.) and the carousel is not paused.