# How these logical operators work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how this line works:

```
var dependencies = mod && mod.dependencies || [];
```

This line of code exists within a function that takes mod as a parameter and mod is an object. My understanding is that first it (by the way, for the sake of precision what is "it" here? is "it" the engine?) will check if both mod and mod.dependencies resolve to true, if so, the || operator will be short circuited and mod.dependencies will return. If either are false, the empty array will return.

I don't understand, though, why it looks for both mod and mod.dependencies. Can mod.dependencies exist without mod? Why not just look for mod.dependencies?

Comment: If `mod` doesn't exist, then `mod.dependencies` is a ReferenceError.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol if `mod` doesn't exist, `mod.dependencies` isn't checked at all.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol inside the function of which `mod` is a parameter, it does "exist", but it could be `null`.

Comment: @Michael And a good thing too. That's why the code is written the way it is, specifically to avoid that particular error.

Comment: `mod` could also be undefined if the parameter wasn't passed to the function

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes

Comment: Read more about the uses of logical operators to conditionally run statements in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368314/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-uses-of-the-logical-operator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a common technique in Javascript. It essentially creates a "fallback" in case either `mod` or `mod.dependencies` is null or undefined. The reasoning for `mod && mod.dependencies` is that directly addressing `mod.dependencies` will throw an error if `mod` is null. Therefore, it checks to make sure that `mod` is not null **and** (`&&`) `mod.dependencies` is not null.

The `|| []` part means that if either `mod` or `mod.dependencies` is null or undefined, assign `dependencies` to an empty array.

You can think about this kind of statement like this:

> If mod is defined AND mod.dependencies is defined, use mod.dependencies. Otherwise, use an empty array ([])